# How can i run Spectron test in docker?

Tags: docker, webdriver-io, spectron

I run Spectron test in windows PC. I want to test my application in docker. I am not sure where I can get docker image for Spectron.

Comment: Hi, your question is actually the issue I am going through, I assume you went this route due to the empty terminal bug on Windows. However I am unable to make sense of the answer as I am new to Docker. Would you have a repo you may kindly share that illustrate spectron tests operating on docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Docker Hub, there's a whole list of [Selenium containers](https://hub.docker.com/u/selenium/) that are combined with browsers that you can quickly get running locally. I typically use the [Standalone Chrome container](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome/) which is a version of chrome in a Docker Container with Selenium installed (not a grid just a single instance).

To get it running simply make sure Docker is running and type:

`docker pull selenium/standalone-chrome`

Depending on how your local configuration is set-up you may or may not need to reference the docker container in your wdio.conf.js file as `http://0.0.0.0:<portnumber>/wd/hub`